# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{(-1)}^{n}}}{\sqrt[n]{n}}}$ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I got this question in my math paper:

> Determine whether the following series is convergence or divergence, and if it’s convergence, determine whether it’s absolute convergence or not:
> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{(-1)}^{n}}}{\sqrt[n]{n}}}$

So first I check the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\left| \frac{{{(-1)}^{n}}}{\sqrt[n]{n}} \right|}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}=\infty }$ because $\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}=1$ so the series is not absolute convergence. Next I tried to check if it's convergent or divergent, I tried the ratio test, the root test but both of them equal to 1 so I couldn’t come to any conclusion. I checked Wolfram Alpha and it said that this series is divergent, because the $\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{{{(-1)}^{n}}}{\sqrt[n]{n}}$is indeterminate. I tried to prove that $\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{{{(-1)}^{n}}}{\sqrt[n]{n}}$can’t be equal to 0 by using the ε-δ limit definition and it kind of work but is there any other way to prove the series is divergent

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}} \nrightarrow 0$, $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[n]{n}} \nrightarrow 0$.

Comment: To expand: $$n^{1/n}\to1,\,n^{-1/n}\to1$$

Comment: For any convergent series (absolutely convergent or not), the limit of the nth term as n ⟶∞ must be zero.